# how to show MDI child in front of panel

Tags: c#, mdi

I have a `panel` on my main `form`. The rest is empty. I can call an `MDI child`, and position it on the main `form`. I want the `child form` to be in front of the `panel`, but I can not get this done. I sent the panel to the  back and brought the child form to front `(sentToBack(), bringToFront())`. `sentToBack()` solves a part of the problem, the `child form` is fully shown, but the `panel` should stay on the background.

How do I get the `childform` on top of the panel?

Thanks in advance,
[image: The image shows what happens. Bottom half is when button is clicked. The form on the bottom half should overlay the top ribbon]

To make the image more clear: this are 2 screenshots of my program, the panel with all buttons is removed after the button click. The panel on the bottom half is on the right position.

EDIT: I do not allow users to move the `child forms`, I just want to use them as `dropdown` menus with more functions, or as easy way to have more space in my mainform (I want only one form). I could do this with panels, but that is very hard to maintain :)

Comment: You want to position your child right above your panel in parent form?

Comment: The panel functions as a ribbon, i have a button which should show a childform partly over the empty form, and partly over the panel I'll add a screenshot

Comment: This is problematic because the MDI parent is not designed to host any controls except one. This control (which you can access using raw Windows API) is so called MDI client, it takes the whole client area of the MDI parent and is only designed to host MDI children. (look http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/309232/Csharp-net-How-to-bring-a-MDI-child-form-to-the-fr)